# using simpledateformat to parse string date with 6 digit of milliseconds

Tags: java

I am trying to parse String date to a particular date format, but when I used options available from `SimpleDateFormat` I always get different result. This is the string i am trying to parse:

```
String datetToParse = ""2019-07-04 00:32:08:627158"" into  04-JUL-19 12.32.08.627158000 AM.
```

Can i achieve this using simpledateformat or any other date formatter? Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date = "2019-07-04 00:32:08:627158";

        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yymmdd");
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d= sf.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(d);

    }

}
```

Comment: what output are you expecting ?

Comment: Does your input look like `190704`? Then why are you trying to parse it with that format? Also `mm` is minutes (so that would be `193204`... i.e. your format is not correct). Here's a useful trick: `System.out.println(sf.format(new Date()));` if that doesn't look like your input, then the format is not right.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes my format is not correct , I tried many other options from simpedateformat but could not get desire output. this is my desire output:04-JUL-19 12.32.08.627158000 AM.

Comment: Start with parsing your input before you try to create your output. Word of warning, your format appears to include nanoseconds; that's not going to be easy to parse.

Comment: how do you get `12 AM` in output ? are you looking for this `2019-Jul-04 00:32:08:627158000 AM` @MaheshMishra ?

Comment: 00 = 12 (midnight), I got great answer from elliot. apreciated for your effort deadpool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the long deprecated `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date`, you should use the new [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) in the `java.time` and `java.time.format` packages. If for no other reason than [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) does not offer nanosecond resolution (and your input appears to have nanoseconds).

Something like,

```
String date = "2019-07-04 00:32:08:627158";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:m:ss:nnnnnn");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
    "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.nnnnnn a");
System.out.println(outFormatter.format(ldt));
```

Outputs

```
04-Jul-19 12.32.08.627158 AM
```

If you want `JUL` add a `toUpperCase()` call, and if you need a literal extra three zeros add them in the `outFormatter`. Like,

```
DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.nnnnnn000 a");
System.out.println(outFormatter.format(ldt).toUpperCase());
```

Outputs

```
04-JUL-19 12.32.08.627158000 AM
```

It isn't clear where those three zeros came from, if you wanted more precision I would have used

```
DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.nnnnnnnnn a");
System.out.println(outFormatter.format(ldt).toUpperCase());
```

But that outputs (as I would expect)

```
04-JUL-19 12.32.08.000627158 AM
```

Comment: There are two bugs in your code. It first parses `2019-07-04 00:32:08:627158` into `2019-07-04T00:32:08.000627158`. The fractional digits are shifted 3 positions to the right. It then formats `2019-07-04T00:32:08.000627158` into `04-jul.-19 12.32.08.627158 AM`. This time the same digits are shifted 3 positions to the left. So the two bugs balance out and you didn’t discover. For correct code use `SSSSSS` instead of `nnnnnn` in the first formatter and `SSSSSSSSS` in the second.

Answer (score 0):

If your fractional part is microseconds written as a number between 0 and 6 digits (up to 999,999 microseconds), then you can specify `ChronoFIeld.MICRO_OF_SECOND` in your formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter msecFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:")
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, false)
    .toFormatter();

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-07-04 00:32:08:627158", msecFormatter);
DateTimeFormatter nsFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.n a");
System.out.println(nsFormatter.format(ldt).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Your `nsFormatter` is not correct. It gives the correct output in this example, but for example `2019-07-04 00:32:08:007158` is formatted into `04-JUL.-19 12.32.08.7158000 AM`. The fractional digits have been shifted left two positions.

Comment: @OleV.V. It's correct. Note the units. This assumes the input format uses *microseconds* (the fractional part is 6 digits) and the output uses ISO-8601 *nanoseconds* (1 us = 1,000 ns).